# Magento 2: Get price for every attribute

Tags: product, magento2.3, configurable-product, product-attribute, price

I want to get price per attribute (this price will change when I change color or other attributes).

Here is the method that shows the estheics swatch:

```
protected function extractNecessarySwatchData(array $swatchDataArray)
{
    $result['type'] = $swatchDataArray['type'];

    if ($result['type'] == Swatch::SWATCH_TYPE_VISUAL_IMAGE && !empty($swatchDataArray['value'])) {
        $result['value'] = $this->swatchMediaHelper->getSwatchAttributeImage(
            Swatch::SWATCH_IMAGE_NAME,
            $swatchDataArray['value']
        );
        $result['thumb'] = $this->swatchMediaHelper->getSwatchAttributeImage(
            Swatch::SWATCH_THUMBNAIL_NAME,
            $swatchDataArray['value']
        );
    } else {
        $result['value'] = $swatchDataArray['value'];
    }

    return $result;
}
```

[image]

I want to have something like this:

```
        $result['value'] = $swatchDataArray['value'] . '-' . $_price;
```

For example, I want to have Silver - 1200 EUR, Bronze - 1000 EUR, Metal - 800 EUR.

Like in this website: https://www.backmarket.fr/iphone-8-64-go-or-debloque-tout-operateur-pas-cher/36829.html#?l=3

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved via configurable product.
When adding a product, select the dropdown arrow near add product button and then after adding name and price for the product, scroll down to the configuration dropdown and then

[image: create cofiguration button]

and you will see this screen emerge from the left side. Here you can create your own attributes. I'm using mine lol.

[image: configuration screen]

Then click next, on this page you need to select the attributes of the product that you want to display

[image: select attributes]

Then click next and you will see the below screen, here you can add separate price for each variation that you want.

[image: price for variations]

Comment: I have variations. But what I want is to show the price near esthetics attribute.
http://dev.neracomputers.ro/en/roms9ds_glxy.html
Ex: Bronze - 1200
Like on this website: https://www.backmarket.fr/iphone-8-64-go-or-debloque-tout-operateur-pas-cher/36829.html#?l=3